# Code can't return key

Tags: qiskit

This qiskit code has not returned any key value. kindly help me to understand where I made a mistake.

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, execute, Aer

def gpu_example(matrix1, matrix2):
    # Convert input matrices to PyTorch tensors and move to GPU
    tensor1 = torch.tensor(matrix1).to("cuda")
    tensor2 = torch.tensor(matrix2).to("cuda")

    # Perform matrix multiplication on the GPU
    result = torch.mm(tensor1, tensor2)

    # Move the result back to CPU and convert to a NumPy array
    result = result.cpu().numpy()
    
    return result

def quantum_key_generation_grover():
    # Define the quantum and classical registers
    q = QuantumRegister(1)
    c = ClassicalRegister(1)

    # Create the quantum circuit
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(q, c)

    # Apply Grover's algorithm quantum operation
    circuit.h(q[0])
    circuit.x(q[0])
    circuit.h(q[0])

    # Measure the qubit
    circuit.measure(q, c)

    # Execute the circuit on a quantum simulator
    backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    job = execute(circuit, backend, shots=1)

    # Extract the key from the measurement result
    key = np.binary_repr(job.result().get_counts(circuit))

    return key
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Result.get_counts`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.result.Result.get_counts.html) returns a dictionary (if you are running one circuit) or a list of dictionaries ((if you are running multiple circuits))
In your case you are simulating one circuit, so you should expect a dictionary where the keys are the measurements in binary format:

```
{'0': 1}
```

Here, the value equals one because you set number of shots to `1`.

So, you should replace the line:

```
key = np.binary_repr(job.result().get_counts(circuit))
```

with:

```
key = list(job.result().get_counts(circuit))[0]
```